# How do I profile a tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand what bottlenecks I have in my `input_fn` with `tf.data.Dataset` so I figured I'd use `tf.profiler` but it only shows the iterator op. How can I get the profiler to output the relevant ops in my Dataset pipeline instead?

## Example

```
dataset = input_fn()
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
minibatch = iterator.get_next()
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
with tf.Session() as session:
    features, labels = session.run(minibatch, 
                                   options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
                                   run_metadata=run_metadata)

tf.profiler.advise(tf.get_default_graph(), run_metadata)
```

**Output:**

```
checkers {
  key: "AcceleratorUtilizationChecker"
  value {
  }
}
checkers {
  key: "ExpensiveOperationChecker"
  value {
    reports: "top 1 operation type: IteratorGetNext, cpu: 79.89sec, accelerator: 0us, total: 79.89sec (99.96%)\ntop 2 operation type: OneShotIterator, cpu: 27.92ms, accelerator: 0us, total: 27.92ms (0.03%)\ntop 3 operation type: _retval_IteratorGetNext_3_3, cpu: 57us, accelerator: 0us, total: 57us (0.00%)"
    reports: "top 1 graph node: IteratorGetNext, cpu: 79.89sec, accelerator: 0us, total: 79.89sec\ntop 2 graph node: OneShotIterator, cpu: 27.92ms, accelerator: 0us, total: 27.92ms"
    reports: "<ipython-input-2-c5f67ba0356f>:49:<module>, cpu: 79.89sec, accelerator: 0us, total: 79.89sec\n<ipython-input-2-c5f67ba0356f>:48:<module>, cpu: 27.92ms, accelerator: 0us, total: 27.92ms"
  }
}
checkers {
  key: "OperationChecker"
  value {
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find why dataset not show in profile?

Comment: I suspect you need to put tf.RunMetadata() before the first line dataset = input_fn().

Comment: use nvidia-profiler.

Comment: Hi, what's the tensorflow version the above example code used?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `tf.data` profiling wasn't implemented. It seems to be added in version `1.14`. This snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(30)
dataset = dataset.repeat()

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
minibatch = iterator.get_next()
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(minibatch, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

tf.profiler.advise(tf.get_default_graph(), run_metadata)
```

Outputs:

```
Parsing Inputs...

ExpensiveOperationChecker:
top 1 operation type: OneShotIterator, cpu: 3.01ms, accelerator: 0us, total: 3.01ms (87.19%)
top 2 operation type: IteratorGetNext, cpu: 440us, accelerator: 0us, total: 440us (12.75%)
top 3 operation type: _retval_IteratorGetNext_0_0, cpu: 2us, accelerator: 0us, total: 2us (0.06%)
top 1 graph node: OneShotIterator, cpu: 3.01ms, accelerator: 0us, total: 3.01ms
top 2 graph node: IteratorGetNext, cpu: 440us, accelerator: 0us, total: 440us
test.py:7:<module>, cpu: 3.01ms, accelerator: 0us, total: 3.01ms

OperationChecker:

AcceleratorUtilizationChecker:
```